# Parsing a specific format in txt to dataframe in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

This is my problem, I have a txt file (utf-8), with the following format:

```
años ---> cáncer
cáncer ---> riesgo
riesgo ---> cáncer
```

And I have a matrix (LSA space), in which "años", "cáncer", "riesgo" are rownames. What I want is read from .txt and store in a dataframe the "vectors" as follows:

```
    ant conseq
1   años cáncer
2 cáncer riesgo
3 riesgo cáncer
```

Is there a way for doing this "efficiently"?

Comment: Try `read.table(mytextfile.txt)[-2]` to take out the arrows that will be in the second column.

Comment: Yep, or `read.table(text="años ---> cáncer\ncáncer ---> riesgo", colClasses=c(NA, "NULL", NA), col.names=c("ant", NA, "cons"))`.

Comment: wow, that actually works :O